# Cant fill json array to array list android development

Tags: java, android, arrays, kotlin, android-volley

I was trying to send json array from my web into an arraylist in a class with volley libarary

Here is array that i want to be filled

i want to replace dummy data in function getBestSelling() with data from web

Filename = DummyDataSource.kt (it is just plain kotlin class)

```
fun getBestSelling(): Observable<ArrayList<ProductEntity>> {

        val dummy1 = ProductEntity(name = "Bell Pepper Red", description = "1kg, Priceg",
            price = 20000,
            picture = R.drawable.iv_pepper_red,
            id = 5
        )
        val dummy2 = ProductEntity(name = "Beef bone", description = "1kg, Priceg",
            price = 25000,
            picture = R.drawable.iv_beef_bone,
            id = 6
        )
        val dummy3 = ProductEntity(name = "Boiler Chicken", description = "1kg, Priceg",
            price = 15000,
            picture = R.drawable.iv_boiler_chicken,
            id = 7
        )
        val dummy4 = ProductEntity(name = "Ginger", description = "250gm, Priceg",
            price = 22000,
            picture = R.drawable.iv_ginger,
            id = 4
        )

        val data = listOf(dummy1, dummy2, dummy3, dummy4)
        return Observable.just(ArrayList(data))
}
```

Here are what i do to get array filled

```
fun getBestSelling(): Observable<ArrayList<ProductEntity>> {
var url:String="http:// 192.168.56.1/toko-online/mobile/pro_kategori.php"
        var rq : RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        var data = ArrayList<ProductEntity>()
        var js = JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null, Response.Listener{ response ->
            for (x in 0..response.length()-1){
                data.add(ProductEntity(response.getJSONObject(x).getInt("id"),
                    response.getJSONObject(x).getInt("id"),response.getJSONObject(x).getString("name"),
                    response.getJSONObject(x).getString("url"),response.getJSONObject(x).getString("description"),
                    response.getJSONObject(x).getInt("price"),response.getJSONObject(x).getInt("stock"),
                    response.getJSONObject(x).getInt("category_id")))
            }
        }, Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            Toast.makeText(this,error.message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        })
        rq.add(js)
        return Observable.just(data)
}
```

The error come from line "  var rq : RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)"
it says

> "Type mismatch: inferred type is DummyDataSource but Context! was expected"

so i copied this code

```
fun getdata(): Observable<ArrayList<ProductEntity>> {
var url:String="http:// 192.168.56.1/toko-online/mobile/pro_kategori.php"
        var rq : RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        var data = ArrayList<ProductEntity>()
        var js = JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null, Response.Listener{ response ->
            for (x in 0..response.length()-1){
                data.add(ProductEntity(response.getJSONObject(x).getInt("id"),
                    response.getJSONObject(x).getInt("id"),response.getJSONObject(x).getString("name"),
                    response.getJSONObject(x).getString("url"),response.getJSONObject(x).getString("description"),
                    response.getJSONObject(x).getInt("price"),response.getJSONObject(x).getInt("stock"),
                    response.getJSONObject(x).getInt("category_id")))
            }
        }, Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            Toast.makeText(this,error.message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        })
        rq.add(js)
        return Observable.just(data)
}
```

into oncreate in the main activity. But because of that i cant fill array within getBestSelling() in DummyDataSource.kt because the function getdata() only return data to oncreate

Is there any way to make data go to getBestSelling() in DummyDataSource.kt ?

Comment: replace *this* with *requireContext()*

Comment: you can find a whole bunch of posts explaining why `this` doesn't work for context, so if you haven't read them or don't understand how it works, just avoid it using it and use something like requireContext instead

Comment: ok, but now it asking about provider ..?

Comment: @IrvanMuhandis where do you call method `getBestSelling()` from? You should pass `Context` as parameter to that method and use it in request: `fun getBestSelling(ctx: Context) { var rq : RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx) ...`

Answer (score 0):

Move your function back out of onCreate and replace "this" with a context reference (requreContext() or create a Context var in onCreate to reference)

Comment: Still error ... it say i need provider. What should i do